# How to create query with multi options for parameter in graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, github-graphql

I want to create query with multi options for parameter

Example:

My query is `query ($username: String, $phone: String, $name: String)`

When work I can type:

```
`query (username: "08789456")`
```

or 
    `query (username: "08789456", name: "Ryan")`

It can have many option parameter but can not use all them.

Comment: Actually, you can better handle it in resolvers and in the gql schema itself.

Comment: @ShivamPandey. hi, you have example for this. i have learn graphql yesterday. so I don't understand what you said. i'm sorry

Comment: yes, clone this repo https://github.com/shivamkrpandey/accounts-stoverflow and run it. Resolvers are in the schema.js(https://github.com/shivamkrpandey/accounts-stoverflow/blob/master/schema/schema.js) file.

Comment: @ShivamPandey I wrote resolvers look like you. But when resolver have many args, but I can use all or can not use all them. Example I have 2 args is `id` and `username`. Something I use both or only one, but query can work if have one or both all.

Comment: same way you choose field data to return
`addAccount(name: "Test") {
    id
    _id
    name
  }
` or 
`addAccount(name: "Test") {
    name
  }
`